# C problem not showing output with printf using arrays and functions

Tags: arrays, c

i wrote this code that asks to the user to input how many numbers wants to input, then asks for the numbers and from this creates an array then:

1. call the function VerificaSequenza
2. checks that the sum of the first two is equal to the third one
3. if yes does this again with the second and the third equal to the forth and so on
4. returns back 1 if is true false if not

the Question is: why i can't even see on the screen the printf messages? it just finishes immediately without asking for numbers and without printing

```
#include<stdio.h>

int VerificaSequenza(int lunghezza, int sequenza[])
{

    int ContoSomma = lunghezza - 1;
    int casella1 = 0;
    int casella2 = 1;
    int risultato = 2;
    int controllo;
    int i;
    int messaggio;

    for(i=0; i<ContoSomma; i++)
        controllo = sequenza[casella1] + sequenza[casella2];
    ++casella1;
    ++casella2;

    if (controllo == sequenza[risultato])
    {
        messaggio = 1;
        ++risultato;
    }

    else
    {
        messaggio = 0;
        return messaggio;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int lunghezza;
    int sequenza[lunghezza];

    printf("Da quanti numeri è composta la sequenza?");
    scanf("%d", &lunghezza);
    printf("scrivi la sequenza");
    for(int i=0; i<lunghezza; i++)
        scanf("%d", &sequenza[i]);

    int messaggio = VerificaSequenza(lunghezza, sequenza);

    printf("%d", messaggio);
}
```

Comment: Add newlines (`'\n'`) to your prints. The output could be stuck in the buffer.

Comment: Also, if you are in a windowing environment, the programme might close before you've had the chance to see it's output. Running this in the terminal or command prompt should solve the persistence. You might `sleep` at the end in debug mode, but only when you've output a newline.